# SystemVerilog randomization for a fixed sequence of values

Tags: system-verilog, constraints

I need to randomize addr such that addr is 'h0 three times followed by addr as 'hf for two times. The values of addr should be in the sequence even if it is used with randomization.  I tried using a `function` in a `constraint` block, but I can't increment the counter for each randomization call.

```
class packet;
  rand bit [3:0] start_addr;
  rand bit [3:0] end_addr;
   //int count=0;
  constraint start_addr_c { start_addr == s_addr(); }
   
  static function bit [3:0] s_addr();
    int count=0;
    $display("count = %d",count);
    count++;
    s_addr = 1;
  endfunction
   
endclass
 
module func_constr;
  initial begin
    packet pkt;
    pkt = new();
    repeat(5) begin
      pkt.randomize();
      $display("\tstart_addr = %0d ",pkt.start_addr);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Your description refers to *addr* but your code does not mention it. It would help to see examples of set of random values you want generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `post_randomize` function to increment the count:

```
class packet;
 rand bit [3:0] start_addr;
 rand bit [3:0] end_addr;
 int count=0;
 constraint start_addr_c { 
    if (count < 3) {
        start_addr == 0;
    } else {
        start_addr == 'hf;
    }
 }
  
 function void post_randomize;
   $display("count = %0d",count);
   count++;
 endfunction
endclass

module func_constr;
 initial begin
   packet pkt;
   pkt = new();
   repeat (5) begin
     void'(pkt.randomize());
     $display("\tstart_addr = %0d ", pkt.start_addr);
   end
 end
endmodule
```

Prints:

```
count = 0
    start_addr = 0 
count = 1
    start_addr = 0 
count = 2
    start_addr = 0 
count = 3
    start_addr = 15 
count = 4
    start_addr = 15
```